# ¿Que etiqueta HTML es la adecuada para colocar una fecha?

Tags: html, time

¿esta estará bien? :

```
<time>6 Sep 2017</time>
```

¿o podria ser cualquier otra, por ejemplo un `<p> <span>`?
es que quiero tener en cuenta la semantica

Comment: tu pregunta es muy global , trata de cambiarla, pero a grandes razgo te puedo decir que por cada pais y/o continentes la fecha se visualiza distinto trata de enfatizar tu pregunta para que te ayudemos

Comment: Quiero colocar la fecha en un articulo, pero no de forma dinámica. Manualmente pondré por ejemplo "6 de sep 2017", y no sé que etiqueta sea la más apropiada para englobar ese texto. Podría ponerlo en cualquiera, como una etiqueta P o SPAN, pero quiero intentar respetar la semántica, pero no se me ocurre ninguna etiqueta, solo la TIME, pero creo que es para "hora".

Comment: en cuanto a etiquetas puedes colocar la que quieras si vas a editar debes usar un input

Comment: @user58706 antes te sugiero revises [ask] para reformular tu pregunta, ya que esta marcada como de "baja calidad". No olvides realizar el [tour].

Comment: La etiqueta time es la indicada para eso

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a tu comentario usa la etiqueta **time** de **HTML5**: para representar una fecha y/o hora, esta nueva etiqueta **HTML5** no tiene que estar obligatoriamente dentro de un formulario.

Las fechas que envolvamos con la etiqueta **time** tienen que tener un formato determinado para que se indexen correctamente en los buscadores, un formato que no tiene por qué ser el más adecuado para un lector. Para conseguir un formato más humano en las fechas y las horas que envolvemos con la etiqueta **time** de **HTML5** podemos usar el atributo **datetime**. Por ejemplo:

```
<time datetime="2017-09-06">6 de septiembre de 2017</time>
<time datetime="2017-09-06">Hoy</time>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar un input de tipo date

```html
<input type="date" />
```